# Data lost after POST ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been working around on form submission and I ran into something I can't figure out. I know this issue has been posted many times but I can't seem to work things out.

**MODEL:**

```
public class IndexModel
{        
    public string techNo { get; set; }      
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public ActionResult Index(IndexModel _oTechModel)
{   
    //some codes on pulling data from the database

    return View("Index", _oTechModel);       
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessTechnician(FormCollection form, string SubmitButton)
{         
    IndexModel _oTechModel = new IndexModel();
    switch (SubmitButton)
    {
        case "save": //add new technician
            {                
            }
            break;
        case "update": //update technician details
            {
                try
                {
                    if (isValid(form["techNo"].ToUpper(), "technician") == false) { /*do nothing*/}
                    else
                    {
                        _GTechnician.TECHNICIAN_NO = form["techNo"].ToUpper();
                        _GTechnician.FIRSTNAME = form["lastName"].ToUpper(); //form is empty here
                        _GTechnician.LASTNAME = form["firstName"].ToUpper(); //form is empty here

                        _GTechnicianFacade.updateTechnician(_GTechnician, _GAppSetting.ConnectionString);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
            }
            break;
        case "search": //search technician
            {
                try
                {
                    if (isValid(form["techNo"].ToUpper(), "technician") == false) { /*do nothing*/}
                    else
                    {
                        //some codes here

                        _oTechModel.techNo = form["techNo"].ToUpper();
                        _oTechModel.firstName = fNameStr;
                        _oTechModel.lastName = lNameStr;
                        _oTechModel.setEnable = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
            }
            break;
        case "delete": 
            {                
            }
            break;
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", _oTechModel);
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
@model Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessTechnician", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <td>Technician No :</td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.techNo)
    <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="search"></button>

    <td>First Name :</td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:380px;" })

    <td>Last Name :</td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lastName, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:380px;" })

    <button name="SubmitButton" value="delete" type="submit">Delete</button>    
    <button name="SubmitButton" value="update" type="submit">Update</button>
    <button name="SubmitButton" value="save" type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

When I hit the **search** button it submits the form and displays the firstname and lastname of the technician on the textbox but when I change the values of the textboxes right after I hit the **update** button it clears the textbox and the data has lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain again what exactly is going wrong? Do the fields  in the database not get updated?

Comment: What do you mean you "change the values of the textboxes *right* after" you hit the update button?

Comment: Let's assume after I hit the search button the post-back values on the textboxes are "myFirstName" and "myLastName". When I edit "myFirstName" to "thisIsMyFirstName" and hit the update button, the textboxes will be cleared and then reloads the page. I debugged and check and there was no data on form["firstName"].

Answer (score 2):

Your first line in the post method is

```
IndexModel _oTechModel = new IndexModel();
```

You then redirect to the index page with this 'empty' model. (in the case Update statement you are not assigning any values to `_otechModel`)

Comment: I debugged and checked the line "return RedirectToAction("Index", _oTechModel);" there are no values because the code "form[firstName]" and "form[lastName]" that I assigned to _oTechModel has no values.

Comment: @Nate, Exactly (as per my answer). If you want to keep the values when redirecting, then you need to set then in the case update statement (e.g. `_oTechModel.techNo = form["techNo"].ToUpper();` etc. An a further suggestion - you are already sending a model to the view, so rather than `public ActionResult ProcessTechnician(FormCollection form, string SubmitButton)`, you can just use `public ActionResult ProcessTechnician(IndexModel model, string SubmitButton)` and access you value directly from the model (and its populated so you dont need to set then in the case update statement)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did what you suggested `public ActionResult ProcessTechnician(IndexModel model, string SubmitButton)`, debugged and no values still in `model`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change couple of things.
First change parameter

```
FormCollection form
```

to

```
IndexModel _oTechModel
```

as you have passed IndexModel from the form so it will be automatically binded to the parameter _oTechModel.
Next remove the line.

```
IndexModel _oTechModel = new IndexModel();
```

Then change

```
RedirectToAction("Index", _oTechModel);
```

it should be. Look at the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
RedirectToAction("Index", new {_oTechModel= _oTechModel});
```